# Create Menu and SubMenu's in cocoa app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, menuitem

I am developing a cocoa app where i need to create Menu and Submenu's in my application.

I have attached a screenshot designed using flex. How can i do the same in cocoa.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/MenuList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000032i

Comment: Is the screenshot pointing to the top menu bar? or it's inside the window itself?...

Comment: @PuneethKamath... inside the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question itself is incomplete,though will try to match the solution your expecting…The screenshot you posted(you never mentioned the source of the screenshot you have taken,by analysing the design i edited in your question as “Flex”) looks like you don’t want to deal with NSMenuItem and NSMenu classes for the drop down menus…

**Solution 1**: Make a custom View(probably subview of **NSView** like **popview**) that handles input, displaying labels,imageviews etc.

==> Basically,both the menu bar and menu item are wrapped to an NSView And the drop down menu is wrapped to an NSPanel…Well as per the design you have to use NSView,because you will be able to add the corner you like and yes,there is a possibility of adding back ground colour as well…The menu item actually has subviews of NSTextView. If its a menu bar item then it only has one text subview for its title, and if its a sub menu item then it has 3 text subviews, one for the check mark, one for the title and one for the hot key list…No need to worry about the handling the events,the respective classes do their own event handling…It’s quite a complicated solution,but matches your requirement…

Found some example for you,check out this [**code**](http://forums.macrumors.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=336116&d=1334634419) which is in C++.

**Solution 2**: NSTableView with custom cell.Could be fugly, but maybe worth a shot.

==> Create a custom **NSTableCellView/NSCell**,with NSImageView(for icons like Pen), NSTextView(for the text “Pen Thickness”) and one more NSImageView(for the right corner icon) as it's subviews …You have to perform one of the two actions when user hits your cell…(1) If you would like to have the submenu,then again that cell should create one more NSTableView using the origin (***cell.frame.origin.x+cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.origin.y***)…(2) If there is no submenu,perform the direct task...

Example: Assume "MenuItemCell" is the custom class name,in the delegate method ***tableView 
  willDisplayCell*** add the cell...

```
   - (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    MenuItemCell *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    result.imageView.image = //ur image
    result.textView.setString//;
    result.imageView.image = //corner image icon,if you would like to have submenu upon clicking this cell.
    return result;
}
```

On selecting the custom cell,

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex 
{
  NSLog(@"%i tapped!", rowIndex);
  NSTableCellView *selectedRow = [tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:rowIndex makeIfNecessary:YES];
     //if you would like to have the submenu,display one more NSTableView,based on the cell origin as i described above...don't forget to add the animation..
             return YES;
}
```

Happy Coding.. :-)